# How to use "dynamic content" as a filter in SAP CDC connector in Azure Data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-synapse, gigya, sap-bw

I'm trying to use SAP CDC linked service in my ADF pipeline to import some data. And also there is an option to filter out some data on source side using "Selection" part of Copy activity source configuration. This part gives possibility to select from drop-down list column and logical operator to use for filtering value. Also there is an option to replace it with entire expression as a dynamic content, but when I try add there any logical expression it fails with error:

> The value of property 'selection' is in unexpected type 'List`1'.

So the question is - what is the syntax of that expression that can be used as a filter on SAP side?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

- One way that you can check about how to give dynamic content for selection is to make a static selection first using any sample condition.
- As soon as this selection is made, the pipeline JSON would automatically be generated. Using this, you can understand where to replace the static values with dynamic content (parameters, variables or activity outputs).
- Look at the following example for SAP CDC source in a dataflow (same approach but different syntax). In optimize tab, I selected partition type as `source`. And then for condition I have first used a static data as shown below:

[image]

- Now, when I open the JSON, I can see how the condition is actually being used.

[image]

- Now let's say instead of 100, I want to use dynamic content (a parameter called `x`), then I can directly edit the above json by replacing `'low' -> ('100')` to `'low' -> ($x)` which would change the condition as:

[image]

- Similarly, you can try to change the pipeline JSON directly to understand the syntax of the how to give selection condition.

**NOTE:** Dataflow SAP CDC allows dynamic content only for value but not operator and fieldname. Check if this is also the case in Copy data pipeline activity.